What base image do I use for my .NET 8 app in Linux container
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that I need to run in a linux container, and I am not using Docker desktop. My problem is that I don't know what the right based to use in my Dockerfile. The first part of my current Dockerfile looks like this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release

But I am getting the following build error at docker build:
Step 1/18 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
8.0: Pulling from dotnet/aspnet
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.20348 in the manifest list entries

I specify Linux container in my API's project file as the following

I also tried
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0

but I got the following message for that command

no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.20348 in the manifest list entries

Any ideas?
Update
docker version result


Are you running WSL2 which enables you to run Linux images?

I believe I do. But how do I confirm? I have a .net 6 API running fine in linux container on the same VM. It's just that my .Net 8 API has this issue.

docker version prints out the OS and architecture it's running, both for the client and for the server.

"and I am not using Docker desktop" - and what do you use and how? Do you have Docker Desktop installed?

Hans Kilian - Updated is my docker version result. Does that mean I don't have WSL2? I thought I do, and my .net 6 version of the app works in docker on this same system.

Guru Stron - I do not have Docker Desktop installed. My VM is preinstalled with docker deaman and client tools without Docker Desktop.

@Alexu We need to know exact details of your setup. If you are using Docker via binaries on Windows Server then as the docs say - "On Windows, these binaries only provide the ability to run native Windows containers (not Linux containers).". And since .NET 8 Multi-platform container tags are Linux-only
